# Largest order of an element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How to determine the largest order of an element in the group $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_{18} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$.

I know the order of the element $(a, b)$ in the direct product $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(|a|, |b|)$. How to apply this result here? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost done. Few more thing to notice.

For any $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb Z_4 \times  \mathbb Z_{18} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$, $|a|$ divides $4$, $|b|$  divides 18, and $|c|$   divides 15.
We have the following possibilities
 $order(a) = 1, 2, 4$, $order(b) = 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18$, and $order(c)= 1, 3, 5, 15$. The largest least common multiple among the possibilities is that of $4$, $18$ $15$, which is $180$, which is the order of $(1, 1, 1)$, and this is the largest order an element of $ \mathbb Z_4 \times  \mathbb Z_{18} \times \mathbb Z_{15}$.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Finite_abelian_groups) you may write $$\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}\cong\mathbb{Z}_4\times (\mathbb{Z}_9\times\mathbb{Z}_2)\times(\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5)\cong (\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_9)\times (\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4)\times (\mathbb{Z}_5)\cong \mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{180}$$

The last is written in canonical form, where each order divides the next higher one.  Once this is done the largest order of any element (called the *exponent* of the group) is always the largest order, in this case $180$.

Comment: sir, can u please elaborate what a canonical form is? I am unaware of the term. Thanks

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_abelian_group#Classification

Answer (score 2):

You do the same thing. The order of an element $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_{m}\times \mathbb{Z}_{k}$ is $\text{lcm}(\lvert a\rvert, \lvert b\rvert , \lvert c\rvert )$.

Example: The order of $(0,0,3)\in \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is $\text{lcm}(1,1,5) = 5$.

Example: The order of $(2,9,3)$ is $\text{lcm}(2, 2, 5) = 10$.

Comment: thanks for your timely reply.